# Problem installing build-essential in debian

Tags: debian, apt

I've been trying to install some programs in Debian and it's my first time using Linux so I'm having some trouble.
When I try installing `build-essential` with:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

or other similar command it says that there's no "installation candidate"

I've searched for the answer in other questions like this one, but I can't find a solution.

Comment: https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=build-essential&searchon=names&suite=stable&section=all

Comment: try to run `sudo apt-get update` first, the package list may be missing

Answer (score 10):

The following error `E: Package 'build-essential' has no installation candidate` mean that you don't have the `main` repo on your `sources.list`

The `build-essential` package is available on the [`main`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/amd64/build-essential/download) repository.

Firdt, you should edit your `sources.list` :

```
sudo apt edit-sources
```

add the following lines ( sample `sources.list` with [`main` and `contrib`](https://wiki.debian.org/fr/SourcesList) component):

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main contrib
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main contrib

deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main contrib
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main contrib

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib
```

Save and run the following commands to install the `build-essential` package:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install build-essential
```

Comment: ok, but how do we do this in a docker container?

Comment: I try to edit sources but get the error: apt-edit: command not found

Comment: @superhero you need to run "apt update" in your docker file, prior to "apt install".

Answer (score 1):

In order for Apt to know about available packages, it needs a valid configuration in `/etc/apt/sources.list` (usually this is initialized correctly when you install your distro) and it needs to successfully download the `Packages` files from the configured network locations. Common error scenarios include

- Obsolete configuration. If you are attempting to use a distro which is no longer supported, the once-correct URLs in `/etc/apt/sources.list` no longer work. The symptom is "File not found" errors or "No route to host" if the entire server has gone away.
- Firewall issues which prevent Apt from downloading the `Packages` files, with similar symptoms. If you are able to connect to the Apt-configured locations from elsewhere, perhaps you need to use a proxy?
- Transient server errors which usually go away by themselves after a few minutes or hours.
- Failure to run `apt-get update`. If the local copies of the `Packages` files are too old, they will point to package versions which no longer exist in the archive on the server.

Less common but thinkable problem causes would be zapping the configuration files by mistake (restore from backup? Include enough information in your question so we can tell you the common defaults for your distro?), physical connectivity problems (the interface is up and you are able to connect to e.g. Google with `curl` or similar?) and local disk problems (corrupted `Packages` files? Disk mounted read-only?). If you installed from a DVD, it's also possible that only the DVD is configured in Apt as a package source.

For troubleshooting in more detail, any error message or other symptom would be useful for identifying the error, but understanding the system at this level is often sufficient for diagnosing it yourself.

A minor annoyance is that the configuration URLs are not plainly visible from the regular Apt output; the cofiguration looks like

```
deb http://example.net/path distribution section another
```

and Apt itself fills in some parts to construct a full URL path to one or more `Packages` files on the server. With the `--print-uris` option, you can see what exactly it's trying to fetch.